# Batch file can't immediately see environment variables created by InstallShield script

Tags: registry, batch-file, environment-variables, installshield, installscript

We use *InstallShield 2008* for our product installation. Product consists of several components. When a component is installed, a batch-file with some post-install routines specific to this component is executed.

The problem: post-install batch files use some environment variables that are set during the installation of the product through *InstallScript*. But it seems that batch-files can't see immediate changes in registry (and newly created environment variables).

Is there a way to accomplish installation without a system reboot?

Potentially useful information: target system - *Windows XP*, currently logged in user is in *Administrators* group.

Comment: When the installer creates variables it likely creates them in the registry and not in its own process. When it spawns the batch file `cmd` inherits the caller's environment, namely the Installer's that didn't change. Admittedly, that's a bit poor design for an installer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with an earlier version of InstallShield. Here's the way I solved it (quick and dirty code).

```
#define HWND_BROADCAST          0xffff
#define WM_SETTINGCHANGE        0x001A
function UpdateEnvironmentVariable(szKey, szValue)
  NUMBER nResult;
  STRING szEnv;
  POINTER pEnv;
begin
  nResult = RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szKey, "PATH", REGDB_STRING, szValue, -1);

  szEnv = "Environment";                    
  pEnv = &szEnv;                  
  SendMessage (HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, pEnv );
end;
```

The key is to use SendMessage.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**InstallShield users using InstallShield 2010 or later.**

**Important:** The InstallScript Engine has changed since Version 2010 for Unicode.

So using `POINTER pEnv;` will no longer work. You must use `WPOINTER pEnv;` instead. I personally use *InstallShield 2013* and everything I found suggested the "`POINTER` approach", but this a piece of legacy code that does not translate to later versions.

I use the following InstallScript function in InstallShield 2013:

```
// Flush the NT registry to all applications.
function RefreshEnvironment()
    STRING szEnv;
    WPOINTER pEnv;
begin     
    szEnv = "Environment";
    pEnv = &szEnv;
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, pEnv);
end;
```

And for my defines I use:

```
// defines
#define WM_SETTINGCHANGE 0x001A
#define HWND_BROADCAST 0xffff
```

So the key here is broadcast [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to all top-level windows. This way they are aware that a system-wide change has been made.